# add two numbers in bash script

Tags: shell-script

I was trying to add 2 numbers from command line and I can't figure out why I am getting the output as 0.

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@") 



if [ ${args[0]} -eq ${args[1]} ]
then
echo "The sum of the 2 numbers is $(( arg[0] + arg[1] ))"
else
echo "The 2 numbers do not match, hence we are not adding up"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a simple typo to me.

It should be `$(( args[0] + args[1] ))` not `$(( arg[0] + arg[1] ))`